# Create new empty lists from items within a Python list?

Tags: python, list, function

```
my_list = ['c1','c2','c3']
```

Is there anyway to create a certain amount of new lists based on items inside of a list?

Result would be:

```
c1 = []
c2 = []
c3 = []
```

Comment: You want to use the list elements as variable names, initialized to an empty list?

Comment: As every other response has said: use a dict instead.

Comment: While it's possible to do this, as at least one of the answers below shows, creating variables like this is almost always a characteristic of a poor design. The preferred way to do it is put the lists in some other container, like a dictionary, and use their names as keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using `globals()`:

```
>>> my_list = ['c1','c2','c3']
>>> for x in my_list:
...     globals()[x] = []
...     
>>> c1
[]
>>> c2
[]
>>> c3
[]
```

But it's better to use a dict here:

```
>>> dic = {item : []  for item in my_list}
>>> dic
{'c2': [], 'c3': [], 'c1': []}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating new global variables using the names from your list, I would suggest using a dictionary:

```
my_list = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
my_dict = {k: [] for k in my_list}
```

Then to access one of those lists you could use something like `my_dict['c1']` or `my_dict['c2']`.

Another solution would be to add the new lists as attributes to some object or module.  For example:

```
lists = type('Lists', (object,), {k: [] for k in my_list})
```

After which you could access your lists using `lists.c1`, `lists.c2`, etc.

In my opinion both of these methods are cleaner than modifying `globals()` or `locals()` and they give you very similar behavior.

Note that if you are on Python 2.6 or below you will need to replace the dictionary comprehensions with `dict((k, []) for k in my_list)`.

Comment: I can't think of any use for your `type` constructor, it just creates confusion